# Why did "apt remove python3-apt" remove so much software

Tags: apt, 20.04

I had some troubles upgrading Ubuntu, so I tried to remove offensive packages by `apt remove python3-apt`, but this removed lots of software, including software center, which I cannot install back because it does not exist in repositories.

How do I get all software removed by `python3-apt` back after upgrade?

Here is list of software that has been removed. Why did I lose all this software by the simple command? I would expect it will remove one package...

```
Commandline: apt remove --purge python3-apt
Requested-By: janbenes (1000)
Purge: xserver-xorg:amd64 (1:7.7+19ubuntu14), update-manager-core:amd64 (1:20.04.10.9), gnome-control-center:amd64 (1:3.36.5-0ubuntu3), python3-software-properties:amd64 (0.98.9.5), update-notifier-common:amd64 (3.192.30.9), apturl-common:amd64 (0.5.2ubuntu19), ubiquity:amd64 (20.04.15.17), ubuntu-system-service:amd64 (0.7), update-manager:amd64 (1:20.04.10.9), python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets:amd64 (1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu32.3), language-selector-common:amd64 (0.204.2), gnome-software:amd64 (3.36.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.0), gdebi-core:amd64 (0.9.5.7+nmu3), ubuntu-standard:amd64 (1.450.2), ttf-mscorefonts-installer:amd64 (3.7ubuntu6), gdebi:amd64 (0.9.5.7+nmu3), software-properties-gtk:amd64 (0.98.9.5), apturl:amd64 (0.5.2ubuntu19), apt-clone:amd64 (0.4.1ubuntu3), apport:amd64 (2.20.11-0ubuntu27.20), nautilus-share:amd64 (0.7.3-2ubuntu3), ubuntu-drivers-common:amd64 (1:0.9.0~0.20.04.1), python3-distupgrade:amd64 (1:20.04.36), python3-commandnotfound:amd64 (20.04.4), python3-update-manager:amd64 (1:20.04.10.9), ubuntu-release-upgrader-core:amd64 (1:20.04.36), python3-apport:amd64 (2.20.11-0ubuntu27.20), xorg:amd64 (1:7.7+19ubuntu14), python3-aptdaemon:amd64 (1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu32.3), apport-gtk:amd64 (2.20.11-0ubuntu27.20), ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk:amd64 (1:20.04.36), unattended-upgrades:amd64 (2.3ubuntu0.1), command-not-found:amd64 (20.04.4), aptdaemon:amd64 (1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu32.3), language-selector-gnome:amd64 (0.204.2), update-notifier:amd64 (3.192.30.9), ubiquity-frontend-gtk:amd64 (20.04.15.17), python3-apt:amd64 (2.0.0ubuntu0.20.04.6), software-properties-common:amd64 (0.98.9.5)
```

Comment: Please specify exact name of removed package. The [python3-apk](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=python3-apk) package does not exist in official repositories.

Comment: in /var/log/apt you should find the log of all apt commands you run, including the one that erased your apps. Check both the exact command you run and which packages were uninstalled.

Comment: And be prepared to reinstall the whole system. By the looks of it you remove something python related in which core parts of the OS rely upon.

Comment: I have ammended original post with log output

Comment: Unfortunately you have removed crucial parts of the system, including the part that would let you reinstall the software. The reason so much was removed is that all packages which depended on the one you chose to remove had to be uninstalled. In future, be sure to inspect the list of packages that will be removed before allowing the process to complete - it prompts for your input for this very reason.

Comment: save data and install new.

Comment: Never remove the default python.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I reverted back to btrfs snapshot before removal and trying distro upgrade again.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you've removed most of the GUI of the system and other crucial stuff; Hope you have a recovery drive- I think it's because you've purged dependencies of python. Having a recovery drive is handy because when this sorta stuff happens, you don't have to look through all of Amazon for ubuntu-usb. Choose the language and the keyboard layout and click the reinstall option. You'll have to reinstall all apps so you made a really big mistake with that command. Hope this helps.